# SVG rendered button re-position on resize highcharts

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular, highcharts

I am using [highcharts libaray](https://www.npmjs.com/package/highcharts) to render a pie chart. Stackblitz demo [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-raebwk)

To render two extra buttons for currency and percent toggle, I used 
[SVG Renderer](https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.SVGRenderer#button) to add and center buttons below center title:

```
this.curBtn = this._chartPosition.renderer.button('$', 330, 220, (function(){
      console.log(false);
    }).bind(this),normalState,normalState1,pressedState,null,null).add();

    this.prcBtn = this._chartPosition.renderer.button('%', 344, 220, (function(){
      console.log(true);
    }).bind(this),normalState1,normalState1,pressedState,null,null).add();
```

On a full size window the pie chart looks proper but on reducing the browser size buttons go haywire.
How to re-position buttons on browser resize.

Here are the images:

1. Full size:

[image: Fullsize]

2. Resize smaller screen:

[image]

Comment: you have given exact co-ordinates in button placement, change it to dynamic

Comment: @PandiyanCool how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Building on the accepted answer had to make following changes to get it working:

1.Swap `plotHeight` (corresponds to y axis) and `plotWidth` (corresponds to x axis) as below:

```
this.curBtn = this._chartPosition.renderer.button('$', this._chartPosition.plotWidth/2-15,this._chartPosition.plotHeight/2 + 30, (function(){
      console.log(false);
    }).bind(this),normalState,normalState1,pressedState,null,null).add();

this.prcBtn = this._chartPosition.renderer.button('%', this._chartPosition.plotWidth/2+5,this._chartPosition.plotHeight/2 + 30, (function(){
     console.log(true);
}).bind(this),normalState1,normalState1,pressedState,null,null).add();
```

2. On chart's redraw event had to destroy the buttons and add them again as below:

   ```
   events:{

   redraw:(function(){
     this.curBtn.destroy();
     this.prcBtn.destroy();
     this.addButtons();
    }).bind(this)
   }
   ```

Working stacblitz here: [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-raebwk)

Hope this helps!

Comment: Ya :). For anyone in future who needs to do it in angular way this has to be the correct one I feel.

Comment: Yup, Makes sense!

Answer (score 1):

Try this out, like below you can get current co-ordinates

But make sure you re rendering your buttons on page resize

```
this.curBtn = this._chartPosition.renderer.button('$', this._chartPosition.plotHeight/2 - 30,this._chartPosition.plotWidth/2 + 50, (function(){
      console.log(false);
    }).bind(this),normalState,normalState1,pressedState,null,null).add();

    this.prcBtn = this._chartPosition.renderer.button('%', this._chartPosition.plotHeight/2-12,this._chartPosition.plotWidth/2 + 50, (function(){
      console.log(true);
    }).bind(this),normalState1,normalState1,pressedState,null,null).add();
```